# 2sxc - access url path id in razor code

Tags: 2sxc

I know how to access url path id for some detail view in visual query designer.

But what is the right way to get this value in view razor script. I know that I can manualy parse path, but I am interested if there is already some function to do that?

Comment: did not know that i can just get it with : Request.QueryString["key"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you already found the answer :).

DNN will map all parameters after the page-url in the pattern /key/value/key/value/key/value

so it will then always be available in the `Request.QueryString["key"]`